# How to split the login and logout time based on hours in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which stores login and logout time. i want to split the total duration based on the each hours.
The Table is like

```
id | tutor_id | login_time           | logout_time
1  | 12       |'2017-02-20 11:20:20' | '2017-02-20 12:10:00'
2  | 13       |'2017-02-20 11:25:20' | '2017-02-20 12:20:00'
3  | 12       |'2017-02-20 13:20:20' | '2017-02-20 13:50:00'
4  | 13       |'2017-02-20 12:30:20' | '2017-02-20 12:50:00'
5  | 13       |'2017-02-20 13:10:20' | '2017-02-20 14:20:00'
```

i want to login duration in minutes in that hour for each tutor_id.

The output should be like

```
tutor_id| hour | Duration(mins)
12      | 11   | 40
12      | 12   | 10
12      | 13   | 30
13      | 11   | 35
13      | 12   | 30
13      | 13   | 50
13      | 12   | 20
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: You're going to need a calendar table for this I believe.

Comment: i am using MySQL @jarlh

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: but i need the hours of which the tutor has logged in. 11 means hour between 11 and 12

Comment: @Praveen Reddy,Do You need only extract hour and duration in each row or any other condition..?

Comment: @Mansoor: i want to extract only hour and total logintime on that hour of each tutor

Comment: @Praveen Reddy,I replied some query,is it ok..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below approach.

I have created a temp table like below,

```
create table schedule_temp as 
select id, tutor_id, login, logout, 
       case 
        when Extract(hour from logout) > Extract(hour from login) 
          then 1 
        else 0 
       end isUnionRequired 
from schedule_table
```

then using that temp table, I have used the below query to get the expected result

```
select tutor_id, hour, sum(minute_value) Duration 
from(
    select tutor_id, login, Extract(hour from login) hour, 60-Extract(minute from login) minute_value
     from schedule_temp
     where isUnionRequired = 1
    union all
    select tutor_id, login, Extract(hour from login), Extract(minute from logout) - Extract(minute from login)
     from schedule_temp
     where isUnionRequired = 0
    union all 
    select tutor_id, logout, Extract(hour from logout), Extract(minute from logout)
     from schedule_temp
     where isUnionRequired = 1) t1
group by tutor_id, hour;
```

The above query gave me below result

I got the below result,

[image]

You can simply have this entire flow into a stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Use DATE built in functions

```
CREATE TABLE #Table(id INT,tutor_id INT, login_time DATETIME, logout_time  
DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Table(id ,tutor_id ,login_time,logout_time)
SELECT 1  ,12,'2017-02-20 11:20:20' ,'2017-02-20 12:10:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 2  ,13,'2017-02-20 11:25:20' ,'2017-02-20 12:20:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 3  ,12,'2017-02-20 13:20:20' ,'2017-02-20 13:50:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 4  ,13,'2017-02-20 12:30:20' ,'2017-02-20 12:50:00'UNION ALL 
SELECT 5  ,13,'2017-02-20 13:10:20' ,'2017-02-20 14:20:00'

SELECT tutor_id , EXTRACT(HOUR, login_time) ,     
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,login_time,logout_time)
FROM #Table
```

Comment: This is far from the requirements.  Just take the first record.  You would report this as `11` hour having 50 minutes.  But in reality, the OP wants `11` hour with 40 minutes and `12` hour with 10 minutes.